# Qual problema com as minhas saídas da tabela verdade?

Tags: tabela-verdade, circuitos-lógicos, mapa-karnaugh

Estou treinando como extrair uma tabela verdade, a partir de um enunciado em português, o qual peguei o seguinte exercício:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A figura acima representa o cruzamento das ruas A e B. Neste cruzamento queremos instalar um sistema automático para os semáforos com as seguintes características:

- **1)** Quando houver carros transitando somente na Rua B, o semáforo 2 deverá permanecer verde para que estas viaturas possam trafegar livremente.
- **2)** Quando houver carros transitando somente na Rua A, o semáforo 1 deverá permanecer verde pelo mesmo motivo.
- **3)** Quando houver carros transitando nas Ruas A e B, deveremos abrir o semáforo para a Rua A, pois é preferencial.

Após isto indo para as respostas o autor me diz o seguinte:

> A **situação 0 (A = 0 e B = 0)** representa a **ausência de veículos em ambas as ruas**. Se não temos carros, **tanto faz qual sinal permanece aberto**. Vamos adotar, por exemplo, que o verde do sinal 2 permaneça acesso. Neste caso, preenchemos a tabela verdade da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo o resultado da **tabela verdade** do autor é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida após a aplicação do **mapa k**, segundo autor o **circuito lógico** é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue agora o que **EU FIZ**:

**PS:** O restante da saída é idêntica ao do autor!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mapa K** para as saídas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Qual a minha dificuldade?**

> - **1)** Fiz o inverso do autor em relação as primeiras saídas (A=0 e B=0), por conta da afirmação do mesmo descrita acima. Então qual é o problema que está ocorrendo com a minha tabela verdade?
> - **2)** Seguindo princípio da pergunta (1), porque o meu mapa K está tendo problemas?
> - **3)** Qual o modo correto de analisar esta situação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)No seu caso, você arbitrou que caso não haja carros passando em nenhuma das ruas, o sinal da rua 1 fica verde, e o da rua 2 vermelho.
Isso não é nenhum problema. Qualquer combinação de valores para a tabela verdade é válida.

2) Se entendi bem, você não conseguiu obter a expressão para Sv2 e Svm1. Neste caso, e com a convenção que você escolheu utilizar, o agrupamento (Na sua imagem, o retângulo azul) que você deve fazer contem um só elemento.
Não se é obrigado a fazer agrupamentos com mais de um elemento.
Em ambos os casos você irá agrupar só o caso em que A=0 e B=1, retornando a expressão:

`Sv2 = Svm1 = A'B`

3)Nestes casos, em que para alguns casos o valor final pode ser qualquer um, costuma-se marcar com um X, chamado de termo "Don't Care" [0] (do inglês, "não importa"). Assim, ao montar a tabela verdade, você pode agrupá-los ou não conforme for mais vantajoso e gerar a expressão mais curta.
No seu caso, isso permitiria você economizar um agrupamento na expressão de Sv1 e Svm2, que ficaria apenas: `Sv1=A`
Na segunda e terceira expressão, isso permitira agrupar a linha superior, gerando a expressão:

`Sv2 = Svm1 = A'`

Fazendo isso, você economizaria algumas portas lógicas e diminuiria o tamanho do circuito. Concluímos com os agrupamentos que a convenção utilizada pelo autor é a mais vantajosa, e por isso o circuito dele ficou tão compacto. Pelo que você contou, ele apenas não narrou como chegou a essa escolha.

---

Edit: Melhorando alguns pontos conforme pedido no comentário:

Qualquer agrupamento que você fizer deve agrupar uma quantidade de elementos igual uma potência de 2, isto é, 1,2,4,8, etc...
Agrupar uma quantidade de elementos maior sempre vai resultar em uma expressão menor. Você já fez isso em seu exercício, na tabela de Sv1, você agrupou uma linha e uma coluna. Você poderia ter, erroneamente, agrupado apenas a linha e o outro elemento independente, de forma que a expressão resultante seria:
`Sv1=A+B'A'`, isto é, uma expressão maior.
Com isto definido, se em algum dos casos **não faz diferença** o valor da saída ser 0 ou 1, como quando não há carros na rua, é bom escolher o melhor valor para simplificar a expressão ao máximo.
No exemplo que você citou:
`[...]só tinha achado um x e somente um bit 1 do lado dele[...]`
Nesse caso, o X está representando que tanto faz o valor ali ser "0" ou "1". Isto é, para o problema em questão, não faz diferença a saída nessa situação. Seria útil para nós que fosse "1", visto que desta forma, poderíamos agrupar dois elementos ao invés de um só, então agrupamos o 1 com o X, pois foi vantajoso para reduzir o tamanho da expressão. Resumindo: Quando for fazer os agrupamentos, as lacunas com X **podem** ser usadas para agrupamento, mas não precisam ser inclusas **necessariamente**. Inclua-as nos seus agrupamentos conforme for vantajoso.

Sobre comparar com múltiplas saídas: Como todas as saídas dependem das mesmas entradas, comumente elas são escritas em uma mesma tabela, como colunas extras, como a imagem que você postou mostra. Elas podem ser interpretadas como múltiplas tabelas verdade escritas de forma mais compacta. Para comparar a saída, cada expressão encontrada por você vai preencher uma coluna da tabela verdade. Se os valores de uma dada coluna conferem, isso significa que aquela saída (neste caso uma luz verde/vermelha) irá reagir corretamente.

[0] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t-care_term

Comment: 1) Eu vi em outros exemplos este “Dont care”, onde no mapa k só tinha achado um x e somente um bit 1 do lado dele, o autor juntou os dois e fez uma expressão. Poderia fornecer mais detalhes sobre o mesmo? 2) eu gostaria de testar a expressão encontrada por ele, geralmente eu pego a expressão final monto a tabela verdade da mesma e comparo com a original, porém neste exemplo como eu faço isto? Pois são diversas saídas

Comment: Ôpa! Editei a resposta contendo os esclarecimentos que você pediu.